# On zooming in and out, an absolutely positioned element appears to move vertically relative to another element. How can I prevent this?

Tags: css, position

I am trying to get some text to appear vertically centred in the speech bubble. This is simple enough using `position: absolute` and specifying a `top` value on the text wrapper element. However, when zooming in and out in the browser window, the text appears to shift up and down slightly, relative to the bubble. No matter what value I use for `top`, the text does not look vertically centred on all zoom levels.

For example, this is 75% zoom in Chrome:
[75-percent-zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFb2n.png)

And this is 80% zoom in Chrome:
[80-percent-zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmJBs.png)

Notice that in 75% zoom screenshot, the text appears to be too high relative to the bubble.

I previously tried using `px` values for sizes and position but had the same problem, hence the switch to `em` but it doesn't seem to have made much difference.

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="bubble" src="img/bubble.svg">
        <span id="text-wrapper">
            <p>888</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 4em;
    height: 3em;
}

#text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.332em;
    left: 0.85em;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    line-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#text-wrapper p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Edit on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-lumiere-cc2o4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**use this css on absolute div**

Comment: if you dont need horizontal centering avoid left:50%

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.